# Striped artifacts on object when applying metalness-map to shader-node

Tags: rendering, texturing, artifacts

i hope you can help me with this.
So i have the problem that my model gets striped artifacts when applying a metalness map I baked out of Substance Designer in the shader node, or even when no metalness-map is attached but i dial in some metallnes via the shader parameter.

I never had this odd behavior before and i don't know where this is coming from.
See attached screenshots for a visual

[image]

[image]

As you can see the image file itself does not seem to be the problem...

Comment: Hi, @Manuel, thanks for bringing this up!  To tempted flag-raisers: although this looks very much like a bug, IMO it's not off-topic, because it can be sidestepped with a setting in normal use.. it's a problem we _can_ do something about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the image texture node that you have plugged into the Metaliic input of the Principled BSDF shader change the Color Space option from Linear to Non Color.

[image]

Edited after reading Nathen's comment below :

> I'm pretty sure it didn't used to be like that. I'd love to investigate that file, it's hard to imagine that's not a bug.

I did a quick check and the change happened somewhere between Blender 3.3.1 and 3.4.1 .

Gif below is Blender 3.6.1 LTS :

[image]

Blender file with packed image texture: https://blend-exchange.com/b/j6Kvwmyo

Comment: Oh man, when did that happen?  I'm pretty sure it didn't used to be like that.  I'd love to investigate that file, it's hard to imagine that's not a bug.

Comment: You are correct. It seems to have changed somewhere between Blender 3.3.1 and 3.4.1.    I have added an example file to my answer above.

Comment: 3fingered .. good spot. +  @Nathan looks like a report, once checked out.. doesn't it? Whichever one of you goes for it..

Comment: @RobinBetts Looks similar to https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/106381 even though it's not a TGA.  I reported there.  It's weird, other images are working.